# Optional math symbols as arguments to custom command

Tags: math-mode, macros

I have a custom command defined as

```
\newcommand{\transition}[1]{$\stackrel{\texttt{#1}}{-->}$}
```

The argument that I pass to the command can sometimes be normal text and thus is formatted using `\texttt{text}` and sometimes I want to pass a math symbol such as `\tau` or `\alpha` or a combination of these.

Is there a way how I can reason on the argument being passed, such as introduce an if then else depending on the type of the parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\mathtt` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\transition}[1]{\ensuremath{\xrightarrow{\mathtt{#1}}}}
\begin{document}
\transition{foo}
\transition{\alpha}
\end{document}
```

You can use `\textstyle` before `#1` if you want lager text.

Comment: Maybe you should explain, that you've used `\ensuremath` instead of `$`…`$` to make `\transition` work not only in text but also inside of math.